# Which method would be better to bind data with UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

For a long time, I have been binding data with table view cells in the delegate method `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

But recently, I read a blog, which is about how to get a better performance. And it tells us that we should bind data with table view cells in another delegate method `- tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, since cells are not going to be displayed in `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

And I try it in my personal project, but it seems weird. Some cells are overlapped.

Before that in my project, I use Masonry to layout the subviews of the cells. After I bind data with table view cells in `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, I call `[cell setNeedsLayout]` and `[cell layoutIfNeeded]`.

And I start to think, which is the better method to bind data? Or, how should I modify my code to get such performance with the least cost(time of modifying).

Comment: It would be interesting if you added a link to the blog post you mention, so we could see the logic that makes them come to that conclusion. The official way to do it is definitely to use `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You should not need to call either `setNeedsLayout` or `layoutIfNeeded`. Show us some code so we can better understand your specific use case.

Comment: Here what you need to save performance for binding data in table view
http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/05/11/reactivecocoa-tableview-binding.html

Comment: This may be the article @YYYeung is referring to [https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.jn0pfy322](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.jn0pfy322)

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is an ongoing debate on this topic.

I think the article you are referring to [is found here](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5#.jn0pfy322). It argues that you should do data binding in `willDisplayCell` instead of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

However, [this article](https://tech.zalando.com/blog/proper-use-of-cellforrowatindexpath-and-willdisplaycell/) points out that the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCell` are performed in the same layout cycle which means that data binding in either place would have the same effect.

The thing that they both agree on is the fact that calculating the height of the row should be very fast. Having a complex calculation may lead performance issues.

In any case, it's important to write good model code so that your view controllers can focus on hooking up the model to the view. Downloading images to display within `UITableView` code and other network/device intensive processes is a generally bad idea and can cause issues.

**Moral of the story:** calculate row height as quickly as possible and write good model code so that your view controller can do less computation.